What tensions arose between locals and the administrators of forced labor POW camps in the US for captured German WWII soldiers?
A 1983 interview of a 71-year-old Kansas farmer named Andy Olson was recently reprinted in a small daily called the Council Grove (KS) Republican. Mr. Olson was one of the many Kansas farmers who used German POWs as forced labor agricultural workers during WWII to make up for the absence of the native sons off obliterating their home country. Mr. Olson got two Germans. They were forced to work on his farm all day every day without compensation, except their noon meal.
Mr. Olson describes one as 5’ 8-9” (172 - 175 cm), slender build, about 150 (68 kg) and the son of a colonel—a career man in the German army. The other boy was a little shorter and stockier.
He says:

Both of them were real clean shaven all the time. Immaculate in their
dress, real good in their speech you know. They didn’t have harsh
words. They were well-chosen words whatever they spoke. And they
weren’t boys to just chatter and run off at the mouth. They were very
serious, deep-thinking boys, matter-of-fact, I sure admired them.
Maybe I’ll think of their names and send them to you.

And he describes the community's response to the Americans running the forced labor camp:

As a people, the people here as civilians, we thought that the Army in
their rules and one thing and another [against] these boys was rather
harsh. They just didn’t trust them no time. And we didn’t have guards
here, [any] time they were out here. Probably as many as five or six
hundred out there at one time and no guards. And one boy I guess did
walk away towards the end of the camp. Well you send these kids out,
the farmer would send them out there, I could be here and they could
be a mile away and they had to be very honorable and they were no
trouble see…

He continues:

Seriously, as far as our county organization was concerned, we had far
more trouble with the officers in charge of the camp than we ever had
with any of the prisoners. Simply because the thought that we as
civilians had, see, didn’t tie together with your strict army life. So
we as civilians here had lots more trouble getting along with the
personnel, the Army personnel in that camp, than we did of all the
German prisoners…

Intriguing. What sort of "trouble" would the locals have had with the army personnel running the forced labor camps? (And I'd love to know the story of the "one boy who did walk away").

I would ask for sources about German POWs being forced to work.  AFAIK, the USA abided by the Geneva conventions and only used POW labor when the prisoners were paid (although paid sub-standard wages) and volunteered (mainly to get away from the boredom of the camps): https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/german-pows-on-the-american-homefront-141009996/  Your quoted source does not describe "forced" labor, and there is no reason to suppose that the conflicts between the camp officers and the local civilians were any different from those around other military installations.

@antlersoft Those prisoners were sent to those camps for the express purpose of providing agricultural labor. This is made clear in the article by Mr. Olson and the interviewer, Tamsen Ellerson's, discussion of an apparent controversy that erupted when the town of Council Grove tried to use the Germans to dig the trenches for, I guess, city sewer lines. Their and other municipalities' attempts to utilize the Germans were thwarted by the inclusion of the word "agricultural" in the legislation establishing the labor program to describe its purpose.

@antlersoft As for whether the prisoners were paid, Mr. Olson claims in the interview that the only pay they provided was "the noon meal."
AO: No, no, the farmer was to feed them their noon meal.
CG: So, you just made lots more than usual?
AO: Seriously, you weren’t supposed to, according to the army, you were supposed to give them their noon meal, but you weren’t supposed to do, fact, you weren’t supposed to do them any favors period. That’s what they told you.

@antlersoft Under the Geneva conventions, common soldiers (as opposed to officers) can be forced to work. But: a) they must be paid a salary equivalent to the civilian worker they are replacing, b) they may not be forced into dangerous works and c) they cannot be made to work directly into the military effort (building fortifications, I guess weapons and ammunitions factories would also qualify).

An old veteran of the 1st Infantry told us a story once about liberating a German POW camp, and how the prisoners were (his words) "stick people". They were so far into starvation that they had to be introduced food slowly under careful supervision, or they'd hurt themselves or others. His unit got so livid at this they went and forced some of the locals to work at the camp so they couldn't deny what they'd been supporting. So that tells me at least that the US liberating forces weren't particularly sympathetic to the locals around German POW Camps.

@T.E.D. Are you talking about POW camps holding Russians and so on inside Germany? If so, the atrocious conditions in Germany at the time wasn't confined to POW camps. Allied bombing was largely responsible. But my question concerns POW camps in the United States.

@CWill - I told you what I remembered from the talk 15 years ago. If you want something similar with actual references, I'd suggest here or here

Related: This question and this answer

It seems the recollections of the individual mentioned in the OP are possibly incomplete. (I was unfortunately unable to look at that source in its entirety since the OP provides no source link and the newspapers web site has the article being  considered premium content and seems to require a login or subscription to view.) Since I can't review the OPs source, I found another source, a  masters thesis from 1985 :

In 1985 a Master of Arts student at Emporia State University, Penny
Clark wrote her thesis entitled -- "Farm Work and Friendship: The
German Prisoner of War Camp at Lake Wabaunsee". It was published in
The Emporia State Research studies series in the winter 1988 issue and
later in the Flint Hills Independent in 1998.

The linked web page contains a lot of good information, anecdotes from both the local farmers as well as from some of the prisoners themselves, which hopefully will present a good picture of what these German POWs endured during their stay at the 'forced labor camps' in the US heartland.
Payment for Labor
First of all, the OP makes several contentions based on the newspaper article which are inconsistent with other sources. There was no slavery involved (OPs tag), and the Geneva convention protocols concerning the use and payment of POWs for labor are mentioned in multiple sources. The above-mentioned thesis from 1985 noted several discussions of the wages the farmers would have to pay, and the adherence to the rules of the Geneva Convention:

The American Army operated POW camps in accordance with the Geneva
Convention of 1929. It stipulated POWs could be paid not less than
$.80 per day. Maximum working hours were ten hours a day, including
travel to and from a job. Employed POWs were to be allowed one 24-hour
consecutive rest period each week. The convention required POWs,
except for officers, to work for the benefit of their captors.
However, the work would not be directly related to war operations, nor
could it jeopardize the health and safety of prisoners.

So the requirement on the farmers to provide a noon-day meal is agreed upon here, but that was just one aspect of the farmers cost involved. Regulations also forbid being worked 'all day every day' as mentioned by the OP. The prisoners were in fact worked for a maximum of 10 hour days, six days a week (Which would be one day less than the farmers put in).
Mentions are made in several locations of the hourly wage the farmers had to pay for this labor, which got increased a couple of times because both the local site and farmers association needed paid as well:

The committee paid the government around $800 to guarantee that the
prisoners of war would be worked and to cover the cost of preparing
the camp for the POWs. The money was refunded to the committee when
the amount was paid to the government in wages. As the committee was
responsible for payment of wages to the government, it was decided to
have the farmers pay for the work in advance. The wage rate for
general farm work was set at at $.37 an hour. It had originally been
decided to charge $.35 an hour, but $.02 an hour was added to pay for
the rental at Lake Wabaunsee. Myers announced after the May 4 meeting
that prisoner labor would be available by May 20.
...


Farmers who used POW labor had to follow the conditions set up by the
Wabaunsee County Grower’s Association. The cost for the use of POW
labor was eventually set at $.40 per hour; $.05 was to reimburse the
Association for any expended it might incur because of the POW
program. The farmer was required to furnish a noon meal, for which he
was reimbursed at the rate of $.25 per meal. The owner had to furnish
his own transportation of the POWs , but he was reimbursed $.01 per
man per mile up to 50 miles.
The county agent urged farmers to cooperate to make the program a
success. Farmers had to give advance notice of at least 12 hours
before a job was to start, as well as notice of at least a half day of
the completion of a job. Farmers had to pay $4.00 per day before the
work could start. Mrs. Howard Myers remembered that farmers often
called at four o’clock in the morning to cancel an order for prisoner
labor. These early morning calls were especially annoying because
Howard Myers, unlike many other county agents, was not being paid for
his work with the prisoner of war camp. According to Mrs. Myers, he
considered his work on the prisoner of war camp to be his contribution
to the war effort.

Similar figures are repeated in a Smithsonian article linked by @antlersoft:

Farmers who contracted for POW workers usually provided meals for them
and paid the U.S. government 45 cents an hour per laborer, which
helped offset the millions of dollars needed to care for the
prisoners. Even though a POW netted only 80 cents a day for himself,
it provided him with pocket money to spend in the canteen.

Towards the end of the thesis there is in fact a summery concerning the amounts paid in this particular Kansas county, showing this was far from free, slave labor:

Wabaunsee County farmers had the labor they needed. An average of 60
to 75 farmers used the POWs at Lake Wabaunsee and more used them
during harvest time. POWs worked 2,507 days in agriculture in
November, 1944. The county agent reported that POWs worked 9,715 days
in 1945. The POW camp was helpful to the war effort. The POWs at Lake
Wabaunsee helped farmers sustain or increase production of vital
crops, and their use freed American men for military service. The POW
camp was a finical success: in return for the POWs’ labor, the
government received $58,693.31 to help pay food, housing, clothing,
and transportation costs.

Perceived Difficulties between locals and camp regulators
The question asks for an expansion on what type of difficulties might have present between the camp administrators and the local farmers. There are several aspects of the procedures involved that reflect this.
These prisoners were in fact transported from the POW camp to the farm each day. This is one of the sources of contention between the locals and the camp administration. The prisoners were required to be back at camp by 5PM each evening. They also were not allowed to be transported by a woman, and these regulations were mentioned as causing difficulties:

The Army also had many regulations in regard to POW use. As previously
mentioned, farmers were not supposed to discuss the war or politics
with them. POWs were not to be allowed to drive vehicles. Women were
not permitted to drive POWs anywhere, even to camp. The Army strictly
enforced its rule that POWs had to be returned at 5:00 pm. This rule
created difficulties for several Americans. Esther McKnight
recollected how she had worried when Figge, a neighbor, rushed to
return the POWs on time, even on slippery roads.

The OP mentions from the interview that

we thought that the Army in their rules and one thing and another
[against] these boys was rather harsh

This can be seen echoed in several comments from the Clark thesis:

Americans often broke rules regarding POW use and treatment because of
their kind feelings toward them. For example, the farmers were not
supposed to buy or make clothes for the POWs. However, the McKnights
bought the POWs straw hats. Because the POWs knew this violated the
rules, they refused to take the hats back to camp, and hung them on
hooks on the back porch. The Warrens of Eskridge also wanted to give
the POWs small gifts, but as it was forbidden, they would merely lay
apples and gloves around so the POWs could "discover them".

Another bit from Clarks' thesis shows the concern some of the farmers had for the amount of food provided by the prison camp:

Many farm families fed the POWs more than they were required. Farmers
served POWs food for humanitarian reasons as well as a reward for hard
work. Kunzel said that the camp commander was concerned that the POWs
were not getting enough to eat, so he sent out a letter to the farmers
that requested they feed the POWs extra food. Many of the farmers had
already been serving extra snacks or even complete meals. George
Diehl, Jr., recalled that the POWs had a poor breakfast of only
oatmeal at the camp, so many farm wives, such as Cora Ringel, gave
them a large breakfast of pancakes, bacon, eggs, and hash browns upon
their arrival at the farm. Mrs. Clarence Gnadt fixed a meal for the
POWs at 4:30 pm before they returned to camp. Myrtle Thierer’s parents
were Swedes who shard their afternoon coffee with the POWs. Lothar
Gilg recalled that farmers even gave POWs food to take back to the
camp and share with their friends. Roger Schwalm’s father used another
method to curb POW hunger. Mr. Schwalm told Ernst Kunzel to take a
shotgun and go out into the pasture. Whenever he was a clump of grass
that had a little entrance that looked like and animal had rested
there, he was to shoot into the clump. Kunzel followed Schwalm’s
instructions and bagged ten rabbits. He took the rabbits back to the
camp kitchen, where they were cooked and served to the POWs.
POWs expressed preferences in food. Many Americans remembered they
scorned corn as "swine food" or something to fatten chickens or cattle
for slaughter. Ester McKnight recollected that POWs also felt that
pumpkins were unfit for human consumption. They preferred the dark
breads common to Germany over the American white and refined bread.
Many of the POWs called white bread "cake" and reserved it to the last
of the meal to eat as a dessert. Clarence Gnadt recalled that the POWs
were "meat and potatoes" men. The Alta Vista Journal, in an article
entitled "Corn on the Cob Not Fit Food for the Superior Race",
reported that they had a hearty appetite for mashed potatoes and
gravy, peas and tomatoes. Fried chicken was a favorite of POWs,
according to Myrtle Thierer.

I guess the section about giving the prisoner a shotgun and teaching him to hunt rabbits might sum up the thought that the farmers were not as concerned about prisoner security as the camp administrators.
I recommend reading the Clark thesis I have linked if you have any curiosity about this page in History. It was interesting, even humorous at times (there is an anecdote about a local farmer amazed to see a group of grown men in the camp chasing around a little white ball-he having no knowledge of the game of soccer...)

Thanks for the thorough answer. I couldn't provide a link because I only have the print version of the article. But it was transcribed faithfully.

I was more interested in gaining insight into conflicts with the Army personnel themselves, not so much the chafing under overly-restrictive rules. Council Grove is very German, even today, and I can easily imagine the locals having more in common with the prisoners than with US Army personnel hailing from Brooklyn or Eastern Tennessee. And what kind of conflict? Bar fights? Lawsuits?

Bar fights might have been minimal. Kansas was a dry state until 1948.

On the other hand, If there were lawsuits, there were bar fights.

How about that? I've been blocked from asking any questions at all! So puzzling LOL
